# Iterate object and get the result in hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a users table in my database, which has rating form 1 to 5 for every user. I want to find the count for every rating. How can I do this with object?

I have a user object.

```
 [#<User id: 1,  email: "email1@email.com", rating: 1>,#<User id: 2,  email: "email2@email.com", rating: 3 >,#<User id: 3,  email: "email3@email.com", rating: 4 >,#<User id: 4,  email: "email4@email.com", rating: 3 >,#<User id: 5,  email: "email5@email.com", rating: 4 >,#<User id: 7,  email: "email7@email.com", rating: 2 >,#<User id: 8,  email: "email8@email.com", rating: 5 >,#<User id: 9,  email: "email9@email.com", rating: 5 >]
```

I want to calculate the count for each rating count; there is only 1 count for rating 1 and 2 count of rating 5. I want to return something like:

```
 {'1' => 1 ,'2' => 1 ,'3'=>2,'4'=>2,'5'=>2}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
counts = User.group(:rating).count
```

**Update**

If you would like to return 0 if no rating presents Ruby gives a lot of ways. For example I prefer default `Hash` value http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_392/Hash/new/class

```
result = Hash.new(0) # 0 here is default value
result.merge!(counts)

result[2] # some value
result[-1] # => 0
```

Comment: I want to iterate from 1 to 5 like if there is no 1 it should return {1=>0} for those .

Comment: did u find any solution @neo-code ? I have similar problem

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the users around, you could build a little histogram in ruby like this:

```
def rating_tally(users)
  result = Hash.new(0);
  users.map(&:rating).each{|k,v| result[k]+=1}
  result
end

rating_tally( user_array )
```

But if you don't, the above sql solution by @gotva is much faster and more elegant.